# What is the meaning of "Progress slashing" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "Progress slashing" in the following sentence,

> **Progress slashing** unhealthy ozone in the western United States has been largely undone by pollution wafting across the Pacific from
>   China.

?

Does it mean " Progress which is slashing unhealthy ozone in the western United States has been largely undone by pollution wafting across the Pacific from China." ?

Or does it mean "Progress in order to slash unhealthy ozone in the western United States has been largely undone by pollution wafting across the Pacific from China." ?

Comment: Can you please provide the broader context of the sentence? The way you present it, it is probably the name of a company.

Comment: Googliing about "progress + V~ing", I can see "the sentence". May I change the example from the question?

Comment: You changed the question completely with that edit!

Comment: virolino // I am sorry.  By what you pointed out,I know that I had a wrong example about what I want to know. So, I changed a wrong example to a proper example sentence for question.I have thought that V + ing, which follows the noun, plays a role of adjective as a present participle decorating nouns. (Progress slashing ==>Progress which is slashing). but now i am not sure that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There are many uses for V + ing. I will not go through them because that is a very large amount of information.
2. The sentence:

> Progress slashing unhealthy ozone in the western United States has been largely undone by pollution wafting across the Pacific from China.

should actually be:

> **The** progress **of** slashing unhealthy ozone in the western United States has been largely undone by pollution wafting across the Pacific from China.

So the structure of the sentence is:

> The progress
>
> - of slashing unhealthy ozone in the western United States
> - has been largely undone by pollution wafting across the Pacific from China.

Explained shortly:

- the "slashing unhealthy ozone" was started and was in progress;
- the progress was undone because of pollution.

Answer (score 2):

> About Progress Lighting
>
> For over 100 years, **Progress Lighting** has been committed to providing a diverse selection of high quality residential and commercial lighting fixtures - earning the reputation as the #1 decorative lighting line among Builders and Remodelers. Progress Lighting's new home in Greenville, SC is a showcase for lighting, lighting techniques and product testing and development. Progress Lighting is the proud recipient of numerous design and achievement awards including the Lighting For Tomorrow award and ENERGY STAR partner of the year.

Google search yielded this paragraph. Progress lighting is the name of a company.

Comment: I am sorry. I know that I had a wrong example about what I want to know. So, I changed a wrong example to a proper example sentence for question.

Comment: I am sorry about changing the question. I do not know what to do. I changed the content of the question, but before I changed it I already had the answer to the question. thank you for your answer.

Comment: Its alright.Glad your problem is resolved.